# Incorrect Count Using Self Join

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm attempting to get a Count of how many times each book occurs in the SurveyDatas table for a each grade and each survey year.

In the query below the result in the Grade3 column for BookId 300 should actually be 1, but instead its 116. And same for the Grade4 column too. If I remove the Grade4 Count and JOIN, I get 58 which is half of 116, but still incorrect. I'm suspicious I need to use a Subquery instead of Left Joins for what I'm trying to do here, or perhaps there's even a more efficient way of doing this. Would SQL Server Common Table Expressions help me out here? I've never used that feature.

```
SELECT sd.SurveyYear, sd.BookId, 
    Count(sd3.Grade) as Grade3, Count(sd4.Grade) as Grade4
FROM SurveyDatas sd
LEFT JOIN SurveyDatas sd3 on sd3.BookId = sd.BookId 
    AND sd3.SurveyYear = sd.SurveyYear 
    AND sd3.Grade = '3'
LEFT JOIN SurveyDatas sd4 on sd4.BookId = sd.BookId
    AND sd4.SurveyYear = sd.SurveyYear 
    AND sd4.Grade = '4'
GROUP BY sd.SurveyYear, sd.BookId
```

And here's my table structure and what my data looks like, although I do have more data entered than what I'm showing here.

```
SurveyDataId | SurveyYear | BookId | Grade
1              2014         300      3
2              2014         300      4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting a cartesian product between the two.  Instead, just use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT sd.SurveyYear, sd.BookId, 
       sum(case when sd.Grade = '3' then 1 else 0 end) as Grade3,
       sum(case when sd.Grade = '4' then 1 else 0 end) as Grade4
FROM SurveyDatas sd
GROUP BY sd.SurveyYear, sd.BookId;
```

The self-join is not necessary.

Comment: It works great! My Grade field actually is text/varchar to accommodate K for kindergarten and because we aren't doing calculations on the data, but that's sort of irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

When you self join, you need to consider all columns.  You aren't using the SurverDataID, and not getting the full picture because of it.  Include it in you join condition, and you'll see what you expect.

```
SELECT sd.SurveyYear, sd.BookId, 
    Count(sd3.Grade) as Grade3, Count(sd4.Grade) as Grade4
FROM SurveyDatas sd
LEFT JOIN SurveyDatas sd3 on sd3.BookId = sd.BookId 
    AND sd3.SurveyYear = sd.SurveyYear 
    AND sd3.Grade = '3'
    AND sd.SurveyDataID = sd3.SurveyDataID -- Add this line
LEFT JOIN SurveyDatas sd4 on sd4.BookId = sd.BookId
    AND sd4.SurveyYear = sd.SurveyYear 
    AND sd4.Grade = '4'
    AND sd.SurveyDataID = sd4.SurveyDataID -- And also this line
GROUP BY sd.SurveyYear, sd.BookId
```

When I was trouble shooting it, I removed the group by so that I could see all the rows.  I should have seen nulls for Grade 4 where the survey was for Grade 3, and that tipped me off to the real cause.